# rotate pdf by a certain degree in adobe acrobat

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, image-editing, forms, rotate

I imported a .jpg image into adobe acrobat to convert it into PDF form with textboxes and stuff. the scanned .jpg is tilted and has to be rotated 5 deg. anti-clockwise. I know how to do this on image editor like paint.net. But I want to do this on PDF itself. 
 is there anyway to rotate document/images in PDF by any other degree other than 90,180 or 270? thanks in advance

Comment: If you are fine with a free solution, try [PDFEscape](https://www.pdfescape.com/). It works online or you can download it to your computer. Open a PDF file you wish to edit, look under the `Page` menu, click on `More`, there select `Deskew`. It has worked fine for me just now.

Comment: @RichardHardy why not make your comment an answer? This is what worked for me

Answer (score 5):

You can rotate pages to any degree as well, in the pro version only. Just follow these steps:

1. Use/open the **TouchUp Object** tool. (You'll see a bounding box having a 'dot' on each of the four points of the box)
2. Put the mouse focus on the 'dot'. (You want to see a "+" shape mouse cursor having an arrow head at each end of the vertical and horizontal line)
3. Right click for the context menu and select **Rotate Selection**.
4. Get the tool/cursor positioned on a 'dot'. (You want to see a diagonal line mouse cursor with both ends terminating in an arrow head)
5. Left click and hold. Move/rotate as desired.

Comment: This was for old version of acrobat (<11?). Another solution is cpdf -rotate-contents 3 in.pdf -o out.pdf as in https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.pdf/5rlxgne83wc/SljDH-qZZJ4J

Comment: @JerryT That's an awesome tool to perform that task. I strongly suggest to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there really isn't any way to arbitrarily rotate a page in Acrobat.  However, Acrobat does have functions to clean up scanned images that will do deskewing among other things.  You might find that useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily do this in Adobe Acrobat - as one of the other posters said, you could "edit object" for each page's image, but that's not so nice.

I spent hours trying to figure out how to rotate the pdf file by `.70` degrees, and didn't want to "rotate object" for all 40 pages, and didn't want to place every page in InDesign and rotate it.

You can hardly buy software to do this, but you can do it for [free using TexLive](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tug.org%2Ftexlive%2F).

[You can rotate every page in the pdf by any degree you like](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233513/how-to-rotate-a-pdf).

[TexLive](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tug.org%2Ftexlive%2F) is free (but a hefty-sized install, and a bit of a learning curve).  But once you've got, it works!

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with a free solution, try [PDFEscape](https://www.pdfescape.com/). It works online or you can download it to your computer. Open a PDF file you wish to edit, look under the `Page` menu, click on `More`, there select `Deskew`. It has worked fine for me.

Comment: This cut off part of the text in my test PDF. Here's a tool that worked better: https://supertool.org/rotate-pdf/

Comment: @dca, thank you for sharing this. Consider adding supertool.org/rotate-pdf as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With file open, click on "Fit one full page to window" icon on ribbon tool.
Select the "hand tool."
Hover mouse over document. Then, "right-click" with your mouse.  Scroll down til you see "rotate clockwise" on the drop-down list and select.  This will rotate 45 degrees each time you select, so you should be able to see the document easily.